# Deployment on Laravel Forge throwing faker not found Exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-forge

I am trying to deploy a laravel project on forge and i am getting the below exception :

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
Class 'Faker\Factory' not found
```

I have the faker reference in require-dev in composer.json!

composer.json file

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",
    "dingo/api": "1.0.x@dev"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.5",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "laracasts/testdummy": "1.*",
    "laracasts/generators": "^1.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

Deployment script in Forge:

```
git pull origin master 
composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist
php artisan migrate --force
php artisan db:seed --class="StaticDataSeeder"
```

I was able to deploy the same project locally with out any problem and composer update on forge also runs successfully and i can see the faker package getting downloaded.

Please let me know if i am missing something.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is a clear conflict that explains your problem:

1. You've added the `"fzaninotto/faker"` package to the `require-dev` section.
2. You're running the deployment `composer install` command with the `--no-dev` option which [explicitly prohibits](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev) installing the packages listed in `require-dev`.

So the solution is either to move the package to the `require` section or remove the `--no-dev` option when deploying.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Removed the '--no-dev' option and that did the trick. :)

Comment: Glad I could help. **Small tip:** If you're using the `fzaninotto/faker` package to generate seed data (since I see you're running a seeder within the deployment process), I suggest you move it to the `require` section, because by removing the `--no-dev` option, you're installing `phpunit/phpunit` and all the other packages listed in `require-dev` on your production server, which is not really needed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will move it to the require column then :)

Comment: Manually change ```composer.lock```? Forge blocked deployment: "Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform. Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json...Required package 'fakerphp/faker' is not present in lock file."

Answer (score 2):

Run the next command:

```
composer install
```

And the problem should go away

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem on heroku deployment i think it same, i fix with

1. moving `"fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4"` from `"require-dev"` to `"require"` in `composer.json` and composer.lock
2. composer install
3. composer update
4. git add
5. git commit
6. git push heroku

if you don't use heroku as deployment don't run from step 4-6