# Git pushing vendor files Laravel

Tags: git, laravel, heroku

I want to deploy my project on heroku. I installed everything and tried running database seed command which gives me error that Faker factory isnt included. Checked my gitignore file saw that vendor folder is ignored.

Is it good practise to push vendor folder? Or how else could I solve this problem?

Comment: Not a good idea to push vendor files. In NodeJS projects you usually have a heroku script that builds the project and deploys it.  **I'm not very familiar with Laravel** , but this might be the same thing you should do.

Comment: It is part of gitignore that's why it does not push. You don't need to push vendor folder.  After you pull your repo, `composer update` will have you all your vendors files back.

Comment: I am not sure I ran following commands: inline `git add . ; git commit  ;  git push heroku master  ; heroku run composer update  --dev  ;heroku run php artisan db:seed ` and it still gives me same error.

Comment: it's not update it's `composer install`. pls try the solution i provided below

Comment: you also have to migrate `heroku run php artisan migrate` before you seed `heroku run php artisan db:seed`.

Comment: yes you are correct tried running your solution i think it will work just got some sql errors now. `Connection refused                                                                       
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting`. I probably mised a step or so.

Comment: @zerociudo for that you need to look at your .env file and change the `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` to the heroku db host

Comment: @zerociudo and don't forget about `DB_DATABASE`, `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD`

Comment: @limco thats the weird part I changed those before and its correct, do I need to change it anywhere else besides .env file?

Comment: @limco changed it in database.php (forgot that, stupid me). I think it fixed that, but got different error sadly. Do I need to change redist host, because its default in my project?

Comment: It was a random thought to try that but no it doesn't make sense to.

Comment: Managed to fix it another typo, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `composer install` on Heroku via `heroku run` isn't a good idea. [Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Anything you write to it (for example, libraries installed to `vendor/`) will be lost the next time your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting).

The correct solution is to make sure that your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` are accurate, up-to-date, and committed to your repository. If you need the faker on Heroku it should be `require`d, not `require-dev`ed. [Heroku will run `composer install` automatically as part of the deploy process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#build-behavior).

Aside from the ephemeral filesystem issue, this also means that `vendor/` will become part of the compiled application slug, ensuring that vendor files are available on every dyno if you ever scale beyond a single one.

Answer (score 0):

open heroku command line

do `heroku run composer install`

then `heroku run php artisan migrate` to setup the tables

then `heroku run php artisan db:seed` to seed the db

if you get any database errors or when migrating, try doing `php artisan migrate:reset` then `php artisan migrate`

Also, check your composer.json file and make sure you have `"fzaninotto/faker"` under `require`. If you only have it under `require-dev` then it's not being installed when you deploy on production unless you used the dev flag `heroku run composer install --dev`

Refer to [Deployment on Laravel Forge throwing faker not found Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801183/deployment-on-laravel-forge-throwing-faker-not-found-exception)

And to also answer your question, it's generally better to ignore the vendor folder and use composer to install dependencies, hence gitignore.